# Count integers whose binary representation has multiple of 3 one's from 0 to N

Tags: algorithm, math

How to count integers whose binary representation has multiple of 3 ones from 0 to N.

Constraint for N is 10^9.

For Ex- If N = 64, answer = 21 since 7 11 13 14 19 21 22 25 26 28 35 37 38 41 42 44 49 50 52 56 63 these all numbers have multiple of 3 one's.

I got this problem on [link](http://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/6980)

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a programming problem to me right now. You haven't shown any code, or mentioned a programming language. If this is just a math question, I suggest asking it on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i found this problem on a programming online judge site. How come its not a programming problem, I also provided a link to problem. I just wanted to know the efficient solution to solve it, the only solution comes to me is bruteforce i.e., checking each possible value for a given property.

Comment: Did you write any code so far?

Comment: That is not a programming problem, it's a programming assignment. You are supposed to show us what you did to solve it then explain what didn't work.

Comment: @PrathameshRaut assume `N` has `n` HI-bits, just generate all combinations `c([0 , n] , 3 * x)` where `x <= n` is given and break as soon as the generated value reaches `N`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Int32 number = 10; // Your number

BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { number }); // Initializes a new instance of the BitArray class that contains bit values copied from the specified array of bytes.

// Using linq we figure out if this array has a multiple of 3 '1's
if(bits.Cast<bool>().Where(i => i).Count % 3 == 0)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Some explanation of the third line would be nice.